# Fast Summation in Python

Tags: python, sum, vectorization

I want to do a series of dot products. Namely

```
for i in range(N[0]):
  for j in range(N[1]):
    kr[i,j] = dot(k[i,j,:], r[i,j,:])
```

Is there a vectorized way to do this, for example using einsum or tensordot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `k` and `r` have three dimensions, this is the same as:

```
kr = numpy.sum(k * r, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `N[0]` and `N[1]` are the lengths of the first two dimensions of `k` and `r`,

```
kr = numpy.einsum('...i,...i->...', k, r)
```

We specify `...` to enable broadcasting, and perform a dot product along the last axis.